# How to Dynamically Add Class to div(s)

Tags: jquery

Can you please take a look at [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/fgVGj/) and let me know how I can add dynamically css class to some div(s) which have same id as list items in this case i want to add the `added` class to each div associated with list.
    
        one
        two
        three
        four

and I have this jquery so far:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("li").on("click", function () {
        var item = $(this).attr('id');
        $(".box").attr('id') = item
    });
});
```

Comment: IDs must be unique, use class instead

Comment: You can't have `div` in `ul`. you need to have `li`'s. Your html is not valid. I would correct it first.

Comment: you shouldn't delete your example code.  It just confuses everyone who reads your question.  you should put all code on here so we don't have to rely on jsfiddle being available.

Comment: But I didnt delete any thing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ids have to be unique so you should use different ids for your li and div items, e.g.:

HTML:

```
<ul class="list-inline">
    <li id="one">one</li>
    <li id="two">two</li>
    <li id="three">three</li>
    <li id="four">four</li>
</ul>
<br />
<div class="box" id="box-one"></div>
<div class="box" id="box-two"></div>
<div class="box" id="box-three"></div>
<div class="box" id="box-four"></div>
```

JQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("li").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id'); 
    // If you want the class at one element only:
    $(".box").removeClass("added");
    $("#box-" + id).addClass("added");
  });
});
```

Working Jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/fgVGj/5/

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  IDs have to be unique on the page.

Comment: Ho ps2goat, so is there any solution to not re generate the code for all boxes? there should be a way to stop over coding!

Comment: Sorry I meant Hi not ho :-(

Answer (score 0):

To fix your problem this will work

`$(document).ready(function () {
    $("li").on("click", function () {
        var item = $(this).attr('id');
        $(".box").attr('id', item);
    });
});`

You pass the new attr as a second argument to `.attr()`, however as mentioned already to should use classes or data attributes instead as ids are unique.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/uHP7B/1/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    // cache box list
    var boxes = $(".box");

  $("li").on("click",function(){

      // get list item id
      var item_id = $(this).attr('id'); 

      // check list of boxes for a mattch
      for(var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i += 1){

          // we got a match!
          if( boxes[i].id == item_id){

              alert("match is div containing '" + boxes[i].innerHTML + "'");
          }
      }
  });
});
```